# Regex: Remove every two or more spaces between specific tags and leave just a space instead

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to remove every two or more spaces between specific tags and leave just a space instead:

For example:

`<p class="text_obisnuit">  The context of articles,   stories, and conversations helps you     figure out and understand the meaning   of English words in the text that are new to you.   </p>`

My desire output:

`<p class="text_obisnuit">The context of articles, stories, and conversations helps you figure out and understand the meaning of English words in the text that are new to you.</p>`

I tried something but it did not work

`(?<=<p class="text_obisnuit">)\s*|\s*(?=</p>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes 2 or more spaces only *inside* `<p class="text_obisnuit">` and `</p>` and keep any other multiple spaces.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<p class="text_obisnuit">|\G)(?:(?!</p>).)*?\s\K\s+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`* depending if you want to match multiple lines or not.
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                         # start non capture group
  <p class="text_obisnuit"> # literally
 |                          # OR
  \G                        # restart from position of last match
)                           # end group
(?:                         # start non capture group
  (?!</p>)                  # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't reach </p>
  .                         # any character
)*?                         # group may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
\s                          # a space
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
\s+                         # 1 or more spaces
```

**Given text:**

```
other     text

<p class="text_obisnuit">  The context of articles,   stories, and conversations helps you     figure out and understand the meaning   of English words in the text that are new to you.   </p>

other    text
```

**Result for given example:**

```
other     text

<p class="text_obisnuit"> The context of articles, stories, and conversations helps you figure out and understand the meaning of English words in the text that are new to you. </p>

other    text
```

**Note:** it keeps space just after `<p...>` and just before `</p>`

---

If you want to remove these spaces, you have to run another regex:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=<p class="text_obisnuit">)\s+|\s+(?=</p>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=                        # start positive lookbehind, make sure we have 
  <p class="text_obisnuit"> # literally
)                           # end lookbehind
\s+                         # 1 or more spaces
|                           # OR
\s+                         # 1 or more spaces
(?=                         # start positive lookahead
  </p>                      # literally
)                           # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
other     text

<p class="text_obisnuit">The context of articles, stories, and conversations helps you figure out and understand the meaning of English words in the text that are new to you.</p>

other    text
```

Comment: hello, Toto. That was my problem, I need to remove also the space before and after <p>..</p>

Comment: Toto - I was able to get everything to select in the middle of those tags with something like `^(<p class="text_obisnuit">)\K.*\s{2,}.+?(?=</p>)` so wasn't sure if you have an idea to make that better and then to replace all 2 or more spaces with only those characters within.

Comment: @JustMe: It is not possible to do in only one regex because you want to remove 2 or more spaces with 1 space, that's the case for the left space after `<p...>`, this regex replace 2 or more space with 1 space. ou have to run another regex, see my edit.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: the replacement is not the same for the first and last spaces, they want to remove completely them but keep 1 space for other spaces in the middle.I  think it is not possible with a single regex (or perhaps but it will become to complex!)

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not in general care for blanks.
If you display your HTML you will see that the blanks have disappeared.

I have created for you a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zbr2sxc5/1/)
for testing.

A much simpler solution is to just replace two blanks by one and repeat as many
times as possible, but blanks are really unimportant unless in
preformatted text which is using the
[`<pre> Tag`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_pre_tag.htm).

Comment: hello harrymc, it is not about html, but I want to see everything in order in notepad++, not a mess

Comment: With very complicated regex you run the risk of destroying the text rather than beautifying it. Regarding beautifying : Have you looked at the XML Tools plugin? It might do a better job than regex in making your text readable. It works for HTML too, not only XML.

Answer (score 0):

FIND THE SOLUTION:

SEARCH:

`(?s)(\G|<p class="text_obisnuit">)((?!</p>).)*?\K((?<=>)\h+|\h+(?=<|\h))`

REPLACE BY:

`(leave empty)`